# How to deploy a dynamic webpack javascript chunkfile

Tags: webpack

We have a webpack setup where a base javascript file loads other chunkfiles with dynamic import. Now we want to deploy a patch with some js changes in a single chunkfile and renamed it with the same hash. But we are getting following error after deploying changed chunkfile:

```
libsMin.js.resource.1581412688349.js:1 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 57 failed.
(missing: https://www.domain.name/dist/js/templates.aa8e374955a21a7f93be.js)
```

Is there any way to deploy a chunkfile to work with existing webpack bundles.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating a chunk, we have generated an entry file and loaded it asynchronously with webpack magic comments:

```
// webpack code
const WEBPACK_ASSET_PATH = IS_PROD_ENV ? '/prod/assets/js/': '/dist/javascript/';

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        // other entries
        main: './src/main.js',
        templates: './src/templates.js',
    },
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'WEBPACK_ASSET_PATH': JSON.stringify(WEBPACK_ASSET_PATH)
    })
} 

// main.js code
import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ WEBPACK_PUBLIC_PATH + 'templates.js')
```